# How can i use python built-in function like isinstance() in julia using PyCall

Tags: python, julia, built-in

PyCall document says:
Important: The biggest difference from Python is that object attributes/members are accessed with o[:attribute] rather than o.attribute, so that o.method(...) in Python is replaced by o:method in Julia. Also, you use get(o, key) rather than o[key]. (However, you can access integer indices via o[i] as in Python, albeit with 1-based Julian indices rather than 0-based Python indices.)

But i have no idea about which module or object to import

Comment: Make the question clearer. Ways to do this: a) Add some of your code. b) Explain what is the purpose of your function or what it is trying to calculate. c) Make the code you share runnable and perhaps add some results or errors you get. d) Add a sentence which is a question (? at the end) and try to describe what would an answer be. Any combination of (a),(b),(c), and (d) would help.

Comment: Thank you anyway, the first answer below solved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simple example to get you started

```julia
using PyCall

@pyimport numpy as np           # 'np' becomes a julia module

a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])  # access objects directly under a module
                                # (in this case the 'array' function)
                                # using a dot operator directly on the module
#> 2×2 Array{Int64,2}:
#> 1  2
#> 3  4

a = PyObject(a)                 # dear Julia, we appreciate the automatic
                                # convertion back to a julia native type, 
                                # but let's get 'a' back in PyObject form
                                # here so we can use one of its methods:
#> PyObject array([[1, 2],
#>                 [3, 4]])

b = a[:mean](axis=1)            # 'a' here is a python Object (not a python 
                                # module), so the way to access a method
                                # or object that belongs to it is via the
                                # pythonobject[:method] syntax.
                                # Here we're calling the 'mean' function, 
                                # with the appropriate keyword argument
#> 2-element Array{Float64,1}:
#>  1.5
#>  3.5

pybuiltin(:type)(b)             # Use 'pybuiltin' to use built-in python
                                # commands (i.e. commands that are not 
                                # under a module)
#> PyObject <type 'numpy.ndarray'>

pybuiltin(:isinstance)(b, np.ndarray)
#> true
```